# How to frame sql queries in java without SQL injection vulnerability?

Tags: java, jdbc, sql-injection, jdbctemplate

I have the below code where we are trying to frame the SQL queries based on the request dynamically. But we are getting SQL injection vulnerability. So, could you please help us to sort this out. Any help or suggestions is appreciated. We are using Oracle DB and Jdbc template to connect that.

```
public List<Customer> fetchCustomers(CustomerRequestBean customerRequst,
        int startIndex) {   

    customerDetailsRequst request = new customerDetailsRequst();
    request = customerRequst.getCustomerDetailsRequst();

    List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();
        String query = null;

        query = getFramedQuery(request);
        try {
            customers = jdbcTemplate.query(query,new Object[] {startIndex} ,new RowMapper<Customer>(){
                @Override
                public Customer mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                    Customer cust = new Customer();
                    cust.setCustomerName(rs.getString("CUSTOMER_NAME"));
                    cust.setCustomerNumber(rs.getString("CUSTOMER_NUMBER"));
                    cust.setCustomerId(rs.getInt("CUSTOMER_ID"));
                    cust.setStatus(rs.getString("STATUS"));
                    cust.setGsa(rs.getString("GSA_INDICATOR"));
                    return cust;
                }
            });
        }catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error is ... "+e);
        }
    
    return customers;
}

private String getFramedQuery(customerDetailsRequst request) {
    String whereClause = "";
    String query = "";
    if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(request.getCustomerName())) {

        if(request.getCustomerName().contains("%")) {
            whereClause = whereClause + "UPPER(CUSTOMER_NAME) LIKE '" + request.getCustomerName().toUpperCase()
                    + "' AND ";
        }else {
            whereClause = whereClause + "UPPER(CUSTOMER_NAME) = '" + request.getCustomerName().toUpperCase()
                    + "' AND ";
        }

    }
    if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(request.getCustomerNumber())) {
        if(request.getCustomerNumber().contains("%")) {
            whereClause = whereClause + "UPPER(CUSTOMER_NUMBER) LIKE '" + request.getCustomerNumber().toUpperCase()
                    + "' AND ";
        }else {
            whereClause = whereClause + "UPPER(CUSTOMER_NUMBER) = '" + request.getCustomerNumber().toUpperCase()
                    + "' AND ";
        }

    }

    whereClause = whereClause.substring(0, whereClause.lastIndexOf("AND") - 1);
    query = "SELECT CUSTOMER_NAME,CUSTOMER_NUMBER,CUSTOMER_ID,STATUS,GSA_INDICATOR FROM CUSTOMERS_DETAILS "
            + "WHERE CUSTOMER_ID >=? and "
            + whereClause + "";
    query = query + " order by customer_id";
    return query;
}
```

Comment: Use Criteria https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/gjitv/index.html

Comment: Use prepared statements.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen How to use prepared statements when the number of columns are dynamic. for example, in the above code I may get customer_name alone or customer_number alone or either one. So, how to handle this situation in prepared statements.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the full SQL query (or queries) which you are trying to run.

Comment: The way you would do this with prepared statement is that you construct it with `?` for the values, and keep track which index should get which value, and then when you have prepared the statement, bind the values to those parameter indexes and execute.